# I want to turn a JavaScript array into a nested object form

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an `array` with this shape into a `nested object shape`.
I've been thinking about it for hours, but I can't come up with a proper way. Any good way?

**before**

```js
 let files2 = [
    "folder/empty_file.txt",
    "folder/inner file.txt",
    "user16.txt",
    "reagjjjd.md",
    "folder/folder2/hi.txt",
  ];
```

**after**

```js
let files = [
    { folder: [{ folder2: ["hihi.txt"] }, "empty_file.txt", "inner file.txt"] },
    "user16.txt",
    "reagjjjd.md",
  ];
```

I would appreciate any help or guidance here. Thanks!

Comment: Your design is inconsistent. At the top level `folder` yields an array but at the `folder/folder2` level it yields a filename string ("hihi.txt"). The latter should probably be an array even if it only contains one file e.g. `{ folder: [{ folder2: ["hihi.txt"] }, ...]`

Comment: Oh I understand, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newArr` by your structure .

`newArr1` by my structure suggest

```js
let files = [
  "folder/empty_file.txt",
  "folder/inner file.txt",
  "user16.txt",
  "reagjjjd.md",
  "folder/folder2/hi.txt",
]
let newArr = files.reduce((res, path) => {
  let convertArr = path.split("/")
  if(convertArr.length < 2) return [...res, path]
  let parent = res
  let treePath = convertArr.forEach( (ele, key) => {
    let temParent = parent.find(el => typeof el === 'object' && el.hasOwnProperty(ele))
    if (temParent) {
      parent = temParent[ele]
    } else {
      let tmp = key === convertArr.length-1 ? ele : {[ele] : []}
      parent.push(tmp) 
      parent = tmp[ele]
    }
  })
  return res
}, [])


let files2 = [
  "folder/empty_file.txt",
  "folder/inner file.txt",
  "user16.txt",
  "reagjjjd.md",
  "folder/folder2/hi.txt",
]
let newArr1 = files2.reduce((res, path) => {
  let convertArr = path.split("/")
  let parent = res
  let treePath = convertArr.forEach( ele => {
    let temParent = parent.find(el => el.path === ele)
    if (!temParent) {
      let tmp = {path: ele, children: []}
      parent.push(tmp) 
      parent = tmp.children
    } else {
      parent = temParent.children
    }
  })
  return res
}, [])

console.log(newArr)
console.log(newArr1)
```

I think the array structure should follow this format for ease of use :

```
[
  {
    path : 'folder',
    children : [
      {
        path : 'empty_file.txt',
        children : []
      },
      {
        path : 'inner file.txt',
        children : []
      },
      {
        path : 'folder2',
        children : [
          {
            path : 'hi.txt',
            children : []
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path : 'user16.txt',
    children : []
  },
  {
    path : 'reagjjjd.md',
    children : []
  }
]
```

Comment: I like the way you designed it. If I want to access the object values ​​sequentially, is it better to use recursion?

Comment: it's the same .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that can convert arbitrary folder depth into a tree according to your requirement. It basically builds the tree through text splitting and recursion, which works but is likely not ideal. I wish it were a little simpler, but hopefully it helps if no-one else offers a better solution.

```js
// const path = require("path");
// const sep = path.sep;
const sep = "/";

const input = [
  "folder/empty_file.txt",
  "folder/inner file.txt",
  "user16.txt",
  "reagjjjd.md",
  "folder/folder2/hi.txt",
];

const get_files = (list) => {
  return list.filter((s) => s.length < 2).map((s) => s[0]);
};

const get_folder_names = (list) => {
  return [...new Set(list.filter((s) => s.length > 1).map((s) => s[0]))];
};

const get_folder_contents = (list, folder) => {
  return list
    .filter((s) => s.length > 1)
    .filter((s) => s[0] == folder)
    .map((s) => s.slice(1));
};

const get_folders = (list) => {
  return get_folder_names(list).map((folder) => {
    return { [folder]: build_tree(get_folder_contents(list, folder)) };
  });
};

function build_tree(list) {
  const tree = [];
  tree.push(...get_files(list));
  tree.push(...get_folders(list));
  return tree;
}

const list = input.map((s) => s.split(sep));
const output = build_tree(list);
console.log("Tree:", JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: I was also busy attempting this using text splitting and recursion, your solution is better code than what I have attempted. Well done!

Comment: Thanks @Mini-Man it's a fun problem to work on.

Comment: I agree @jarmod, the only way to solve it is using recursion because we do not know how nested each folder path can get. If there is a different solution then please comment here to learn us! I know with recursion, best practice is to use a trampoline function wrapped around the recursive function to keep the execution on one stack, this prevents a memory stack error.

Comment: other way is using referent of memory of javascript

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, it's been very helpful.